# Why isn't 'this' bound consistently with this Backbone View?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Consider the code ([also on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B83bQ/9/)):

```
// Backbone calls this "view3"
InnerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.parent = this.options.parent;
        this.listenTo(
            this.model,
            "change:name",
            function() { this.parent.onNameChange() }
        );
    }


});

// Backbone calls this "view2"
OuterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.innerView = new InnerView({
            model: this.model,
            parent: this
        });
    },

    onNameChange: function() {
        console.log("'this' is bound to the outerview instance: " + (this.cid === "view2"));
    }
});


var myModel = new Backbone.Model({ name: "foo" });
var outerView = new OuterView({ model: myModel });

// trigger onNameChange
myModel.set("name", "bar");
```

This prints `'this' is bound to the outerview instance: true` to the console. However, if I change the callback to:

```
this.listenTo(
    this.model,
    "change:name",
    this.parent.onNameChange
);
```

(which I've done in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B83bQ/10/)), then my console shows `'this' is bound to the outerview instance: false`. It seems that `this` is bound to the `InnerView` instance instead.

Why is this? After reading the [listenTo docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) I would expect `this` to always be bound to an `InnerView` instance, since `listenTo` is called inside `InnerView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be correct behavior. In the first example this refers to "this.parent" where the second example refers to "this".

**First example**

```
this.listenTo(
       this.model,
       "change:name",
        function() { this.parent.onNameChange() }
);

onNameChange: function() {
    // here this refers to "this.parent"
}
```

**Second example**

```
this.listenTo(
    this.model,
    "change:name",
    this.parent.onNameChange // Reference to onNameChange detached from "parent"
);

onNameChange: function() {
    // here this refers to "this" and not "this.parent"
}
```

**Solution**

If you want to use the code from the second example you could make one of the following changes.

```
onNameChange: function() {
    console.log("'this' is ... instance: " + (this.parent.cid === "view2"));
}
```

or

```
this.listenTo(
    this.model,
    "change:name",
    $.proxy(this.parent.onNameChange, this.parent)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a by-design behavior of Backbone. First let's see how Backbone implements `listenTo`.

```
  var listenMethods = {listenTo: 'on', listenToOnce: 'once'};

  // Inversion-of-control versions of `on` and `once`. Tell *this* object to
  // listen to an event in another object ... keeping track of what it's
  // listening to.
  _.each(listenMethods, function(implementation, method) {
    Events[method] = function(obj, name, callback) {
      var listeningTo = this._listeningTo || (this._listeningTo = {});
      var id = obj._listenId || (obj._listenId = _.uniqueId('l'));
      listeningTo[id] = obj;
      if (!callback && typeof name === 'object') callback = this;
      obj[implementation](name, callback, this);
      return this;
    };
  });
```

`obj[implementation](name, callback, this);` is the place where magic happens. When you

```
this.listenTo(
    this.model,
    "change:name",
    this.parent.onNameChange
);
```

Backbone actually add a `on` events listener to `this.model`, `obj[implementation](name, callback, this);` -> `this.model['on']('change:name', this.parent.onNameChange, this)`;

The 3rd parameter of `obj[implementation](name, callback, this);` actually is called `context` by Backbone, which will be passed back to your callback when trigger events.

The `on` implementation of Backbone.

```
on: function(name, callback, context) {
  if (!eventsApi(this, 'on', name, [callback, context]) || !callback) return this;
  this._events || (this._events = {});
  var events = this._events[name] || (this._events[name] = []);
  events.push({callback: callback, context: context, ctx: context || this});
  return this;
},
```

Here is how it tirgger events

```
var triggerEvents = function(events, args) {
    var ev, i = -1, l = events.length, a1 = args[0], a2 = args[1], a3 = args[2];
    switch (args.length) {
      case 0: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx); return;
      case 1: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1); return;
      case 2: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1, a2); return;
      case 3: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1, a2, a3); return;
      default: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args);
    }
  };
```

Look that `ev.ctx` variable, that's what `this` will refer to in your callback.

So if the callback is `this.parent.onNameChange`, `this` in `onNameChange` will bind to the wrong object.